# Display custom marker with text and popup information

Tags: leaflet, maps

I want to display some markers with previous information and when we click it show more information. I implemented all code on leaflet but I want to try with maphere. This is that I need:

[image: Marker]
[image: Popup implementation]

```
var texto1 = "Código: <br> Matricula: <br> País: <br> Direccion: <br> Velocidad:"
var icon1 = L.divIcon({className: 'enmarcha',html: '<p style="text-align: center;">Test</p>',iconSize: [92, 35]});
var a1 = L.marker([39.2014149305556,-2.1445277235243], {icon: icon1}).bindTooltip(texto1, {direction: 'top'});
markerClusters.addLayer(a1);
```

I tried to find some examples or information at the webpage but I only can insert normal markers or html markers but without popup.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to add your marker and popup appearance? [custom-marker-and-popup](https://tomik23.github.io/leaflet-examples/#23.custom-marker-and-popup)

Comment: I'm trying to add a marker with text, like first image with 'test', and when I click on it show more html information. I have all implemented on leaflet but I need to make this aproach on maphere maps.